# ddrescue: Retry failed blocks after first run

Tags: bash, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery, ddrescue

I backed up a failing harddrive with `ddrescue`. The command I used was

```
# ddrescue -vv -d -J /dev/sda /mnt/rescue/winxp.img winxp.map
```

The program completed with around 60 errors. I wanted to retry only the failed blocks. I found this section in the manpage:

> ```
> -m file
> --domain-mapfile=file
>     Restrict the rescue domain to the blocks marked as finished in the
>     mapfile file. This is useful for merging partially recovered images of 
>     backups, or if the destination drive fails during the rescue. Use '-' 
>     as file to read the domain mapfile from standard input. Specialized 
>     tools like ddrutility or partclone can produce a domain mapfile 
>     listing all the used blocks in a partition, making the rescue more
>     efficient.
> -M
> --retrim
>     Mark all failed blocks inside the rescue domain as non-trimmed before
>     beginning the rescue. The effect is similar to '--retry-passes=1', but
>     the bad sectors are tried in a different order, making perhaps
>     possible to rescue some of them.
> ```

The next command I issued was

```
# ddrescue -vv -d -M -m winxp.map /dev/sda /mnt/rescue/winxp.img winxp.2.map
```

I thought this would only retry the previously failed blocks. However, it seemed to start at the whole process again and trying to rescue the entire disk.

Is there a way to only retry the failed blocks and, on success, save them in the previous image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *same* map file each time - this is where it records the regions which have been tried and whether they succeeded or failed.

You typically do not need to change the command from run-to-run, simply re-issuing it will cause it to re-try the failed regions (again).

---

Using `-m` will (as the manual states) "*Restrict the rescue domain to the blocks **marked as finished** in the mapfile file.*" - i.e: only try reading the successful blocks.

Again, as the manual states, this is useful in conjunction with other utilities to reduce the amount of data read, and potentially reduce the runtime and number of errors encountered.

Comment: It worked. I was recently testing another drive with badblocks, which only records failed blocks. I guess, I was stuck in that line of thinking and understood *finished* as failing blocks that all rescue measures (tried, trimmed and scraped) have been applied to. Anyway, it took some hours to finish but it recovered 100% of the disk. Thanks.